# Multiple rows are getting selected in P:DataTable even when Single Selection Mode is enabled

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, selection, ejb-3.0

I have an JSF-EJB application where i am using  with single selection mode. The Datatable is part of a Dialog which appears when user clicks on Save button. First time, none of the rows are selected in the DataTable which is correct. now when user selects a row. and closes this dialog. and Open this Dialog again. Both the rows in the DataTable are selected.

Below is the code being used.
Please help.

XHTML:

```
                    <p:dataTable var="address" id="confirmDataTable"
                        value="#{householdHomeAddressBean.normalizedAddressList}"
                        selection="#{householdHomeAddressBean.selectedAddress}"
                        rowKey="#{address.id}" styleClass="confirmAddTable">
                        <p:column selectionMode="single"
                            style="width:40px;text-align:center" id="radioCol">
    </p:column>
                        <p:column >
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{address.message}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Street Address" id="headerStreet">
                            <p:outputLabel value="#{address.addrLine1}" />  <p:outputLabel value="#{address.addrLine2}" />,

                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="County" id="headerCounty">
                            <p:outputLabel value="#{address.countyName}" />
                        </p:column>

                    </p:dataTable>

                    <p:commandButton styleClass="fl-right btn" value="OK" process="@form" validateClient="true" update="@form"
                        action="#{householdHomeAddressBean.saveAddress}">

                    </p:commandButton>
                    <p:commandButton styleClass="fl-left btn" value="Cancel"
                        onclick="PF('addressDialog').hide();"></p:commandButton>
                </p:dialog>
```

In the Managed Bean:

```
public void saveAddress() {
    context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.execute("PF('addressDialog').hide();");
```

//*******************code for Persistence**************///////////
    }

Please let me know what m i doing wrong.

Comment: add attribute selectionMode="single"  for <p:datatable />

Comment: That enables row Selection but i need Radio button as a column of the table...thats why have added this code:<p:column selectionMode="single"
                            style="width:40px;text-align:center" id="radioCol">
    </p:column>

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved. I just set selectedAddress=null; and it works perfectly fine:)

Comment: Weird…  what PF version are you using?